# Query to retrieve neighbors is too slow

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x

I have a set of Django ORM models representing a directed graph, and I'm trying to retrieve all the adjacent vertices to a given vertex ignoring edge direction:

```
class Vertex(models.Model):
    pass

class Edge(models.Model):
    orig = models.ForeignKey(Vertex, related_name='%(class)s_orig', null=True, blank=True)
    dest = models.ForeignKey(Vertex, related_name='%(class)s_dest', null=True, blank=True)
    # ... other data about this edge ...
```

The query `Vertex.objects.filter(Q(edge_orig__dest=v) | Q(edge_dest__orig=v)).distinct()` returns the correct result, but in my case it takes far too long to execute.

Typically for my application there will be around 50-100 vertices at any given time, and around a million edges. Even reducing it to only 20 vertices and 100000 edges, that query takes about a minute and a half to execute:

```
for i in range(20):
    Vertex().save()

vxs = list(Vertex.objects.all())
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(100000)):
    Edge(orig = random.sample(vxs,1)[0], dest = random.sample(vxs,1)[0]).save()

v = vxs[0]
def f1():
    return list( Vertex.objects.filter(
        Q(edge_orig__dest=v) | Q(edge_dest__orig=v)).distinct() )

t1 = timeit.Timer(f1)

print( t1.timeit(number=1) ) # 84.21138522100227
```

On the other hand, if I split the query up into two pieces I can get the exact same result in only a handful of milliseconds:

```
def f2():
    q1 = Vertex.objects.filter(edge_orig__dest=v).distinct()
    q2 = Vertex.objects.filter(edge_dest__orig=v).distinct()
    return list( {x for x in itertools.chain(q1, q2)} )

t2 = timeit.Timer(f2)
print( t2.timeit(number=100)/100 ) # 0.0109818680600074
```

This second version has issues though:

- It's not atomic. The list of edges is almost guaranteed to change between the two queries in my application, meaning the results won't represent a single point in time.
- I can't perform additional processing and aggregation on the results without manually looping over it. (e.g. If I wanted `Vertex.objects.filter(Q(edge_orig__dest=v) | Q(edge_dest__orig=v)).distinct().aggregate(avg=Avg('some_field'))`)

Why does the second version run so much faster than the first one?
How can I do this, and is there a way to get the first one to run fast enough for practical use?

I'm currently testing with Python 3.5.2, PostgreSQL 9.5.6, and Django 1.11, although if this is an issue with one of those I'm not stuck with them.

---

Here is the SQL generated by each query, as well as Postgres's explan:

The first one:

```
Vertex.objects.filter(Q(edge_orig__dest=v) | Q(edge_dest__orig=v))

SELECT DISTINCT "app_vertex"."id"
FROM "app_vertex"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_edge" ON ("app_vertex"."id" = "app_edge"."orig_id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "app_edge" T4 ON ("app_vertex"."id" = T4."dest_id")
WHERE ("app_edge"."dest_id" = 1061 
       OR T4."orig_id" = 1061)

HashAggregate  (cost=8275151.47..8275151.67 rows=20 width=4)
  Group Key: app_vertex.id
  ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3183.45..8154147.45 rows=48401608 width=4)
        Hash Cond: (app_vertex.id = app_edge.orig_id)
        Filter: ((app_edge.dest_id = 1061) OR (t4.orig_id = 1061))
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1.45..2917.45 rows=100000 width=8)
              Hash Cond: (t4.dest_id = app_vertex.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on app_edge t4  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=8)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.20..1.20 rows=20 width=4)
                    ->  Seq Scan on app_vertex  (cost=0.00..1.20 rows=20 width=4)
        ->  Hash  (cost=1541.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=8)
              ->  Seq Scan on app_edge  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=8)
```

The second ones:

```
Vertex.objects.filter(edge_orig__dest=v).distinct()

SELECT DISTINCT "app_vertex"."id"
FROM "app_vertex"
INNER JOIN "app_edge" ON ("app_vertex"."id" = "app_edge"."orig_id")
WHERE "app_edge"."dest_id" = 1061

HashAggregate  (cost=1531.42..1531.62 rows=20 width=4)
  Group Key: app_vertex.id
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=848.11..1519.04 rows=4950 width=4)
        Hash Cond: (app_edge.orig_id = app_vertex.id)
        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on app_edge  (cost=846.65..1449.53 rows=4950 width=4)
              Recheck Cond: (dest_id = 1061)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on app_edge_dest_id_4254b90f  (cost=0.00..845.42 rows=4950 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (dest_id = 1061)
        ->  Hash  (cost=1.20..1.20 rows=20 width=4)
              ->  Seq Scan on app_vertex  (cost=0.00..1.20 rows=20 width=4)
```

@khampson's version also takes a minute-and-a-half to run, so it's also a no-go.

```
Vertex.objects.raw( ... )

SELECT DISTINCT "app_vertex"."id"
FROM "app_vertex"
JOIN "app_edge" ON ("app_vertex"."id" = "app_edge"."orig_id")
JOIN "app_edge" T4 ON ("app_vertex"."id" = T4."dest_id")
WHERE ("app_edge"."dest_id" = 1061
       OR T4."orig_id" = 1061);

HashAggregate  (cost=8275347.47..8275347.67 rows=20 width=4)
  Group Key: app_vertex.id
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=3183.45..8154343.45 rows=48401608 width=4)
        Hash Cond: (app_vertex.id = app_edge.orig_id)
        Join Filter: ((app_edge.dest_id = 1061) OR (t4.orig_id = 1061))
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.45..2917.45 rows=100000 width=12)
              Hash Cond: (t4.dest_id = app_vertex.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on app_edge t4  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=8)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.20..1.20 rows=20 width=4)
                    ->  Seq Scan on app_vertex  (cost=0.00..1.20 rows=20 width=4)
        ->  Hash  (cost=1541.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=8)
              ->  Seq Scan on app_edge  (cost=0.00..1541.00 rows=100000 width=8)
```

Comment: Could you share the SQL that is being generated by the two versions?

Comment: @Hamms Added the SQL and Postgres's explain of each query.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your model (in fact, I probably am), but why are you filter on `edge_orig__dest=v | edge_orig__dest=v` and not simply on `edge_dest=v | edge_origt=v`?

Comment: @Hamms I think you are too, `v` is a vertex, and `edge_dest` is an edge so they can't be equal. The `edge_dest` is the auto-generated reverse relationship for `Edge`'s `dest` foreign key. `Edges.objects.filter(dest=v)` would be equivalent to `v.edge_dest`.

Answer (score 1):

The query plans for those two queries are radically different. The first (slower) one isn't hitting any indexes, and is doing two `left join`s, both of which result in way, way more rows being processed and returned. From what I interpret of the intention of the *Django* ORM syntax, it doesn't sound like you would truly want to do `left join`s here.

I would recommend considering dropping down into raw *SQL* in this case from within the *Django* ORM, and hybridize the two. e.g. if you take the first one, and transform it to something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "app_vertex"."id"
FROM "app_vertex"
JOIN "app_edge" ON ("app_vertex"."id" = "app_edge"."orig_id")
JOIN "app_edge" T4 ON ("app_vertex"."id" = T4."dest_id")
WHERE ("app_edge"."dest_id" = 1061
       OR T4."orig_id" = 1061);
```

Two questions there: How does that version perform, and does it give you the results you're looking for?

For more info on raw queries, check out [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) of the *Django* doc.

---

Response to comment from OP:

The query plan for the query I suggested also shows that it's not hitting any indexes.

Do you have indexes on both tables for the columns involved? I suspect not, especially since for this specific query, we're looking for a single value, which means if there were indexes, I would be very surprised if the query planner determined a sequential scan were a better choice (OTOH, if you were looking for a wide range of rows, say, over 10% of the rows in the tables, the query planner might correctly make such a decision).

Comment: Just tried it, it still takes a minute and a half to run. I've updated my question to include the explain for this version of the query as well.

Comment: @AJMansfield: Added to answer with follow-up to above comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are indexes or not on the thing. The tables were just created with ordinary django migrations directly from the model classes so I'm not sure if it created indexes or not.

Comment: In any case though I figured out a serviceable solution for now, just using a union of the two queries. This at least solves the concurrency issue, although it doesn't fix not being able to use aggregations on the results.

Answer (score 1):

I propose another query could be:

```py
# Get edges which contain Vertex v, "only" optimizes fields returned
edges = Edge.objects.filter(Q(orig=v) | Q(dest=v)).only('orig_id', 'dest_id')
# Get set of vertex id's to discard duplicates
vertex_ids = {*edges.values_list('orig_id', flat=True), *edges_values_list('dest_id', flat=True)}
# Get list of vertices, excluding the original vertex
vertices = Vertex.objects.filter(pk__in=vertex_ids).exclude(pk=v.pk)
```

This shouldn't require any joins and shouldn't suffer from the race conditions you mention.